# How to Shuffle a List in Scala

Tags: scala, list

I am trying to read a text file and append its values to an array and print its elements randomly to the screen.

I am using Random from the util library but it's not outputting as expected.

Below is my code

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.Random

object Scala  
{ 

    def main(args: Array[String])  
    { 
        val lines = Source.fromFile("text.txt").getLines.toArray
        val modified_lines = Random.shuffle(List(lines))
        for (line <- modified_lines) {
            println(line)
        }

    } 
}
```

and I have a text file that contains

```
1. ABC
2. ABC
3. ABC
4. ABC
5. ABC
6. ABC
```

So in the end I'd like to print them to the screen such as

```
5. ABC
2. ABC
...
6. ABC
```

Comment: `shuffle(lines)` not `shuffle(List(lines))`

Answer (score 2):

With statement `List(lines)` you create list of arrays and shuffle method tries to shuffle list with 1 element:

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("text.txt").getLines.toArray
val list: List[Array[string]] = List(lines) <-- that's not what you need I suppose
val modified_lines = Random.shuffle(list)
```

Instead of creating a list with an array, just get it from `getLines`:

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("text.txt").getLines.toList
Random.shuffle(lines).foreach(println)
```